# XML error Inflate Exception

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to show HTML in a WebView object, and when I call

```
setContentView(R.layout.help);
```

I get an InflateException.
This is the entire contents of help.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:id="@+id/webViewHelp">
</WebView>
```

I get the following error message:

> 12-31 12:46:04.398: E/AndroidRuntime(18684): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lomda.ong2/com.lomda.ong2.ShowHelp}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class html

As far as I can tell, this is effectively the same as the example file shown in the [WebView Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am able to run this code with defining this `xml layout`. Just try to `clean` your project and run again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use any layout as a parent tag.
Because webview are not container tag Like that

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

   <WebView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:id="@+id/webViewHelp">
</WebView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope its helpful to you ..

Comment: This is not true I think. I tried the xml he has posted and it works for me. I can see a empty webview in my device

Comment: in this case you should pass id of webview using R.id.webViewHelp rather than layout.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is embarassing. I had a different help.xml file under layout-he, and because my phone is localized for Hebrew, that is the file that was opened. Obviously, that file had errors.
Embedding the WebView in a parent layout flag is unnecessary, as Andro Selva pointed out.